# Cross Domain Authentication and CORS

Tags: asp.net, security, authorization, forms-authentication, cors

I have a requirement where my mobile html website(site1) need to re-use Login module from another website(site2). Can I create a asp.net web method in site2 and post the user name and password cross domain and get response back using CORS ?

I want to restrict access to the rest of the pages in site1 , if the user is not authenticated . Once authenticated, how can I make sure subsequent requests in the same session to site1 are authenticated too? we can’t set cookies cross domain can we using cors request ? can we?

**EDIT:**
 I am planning to create a HTML Login Page in site1 and submit username/password using ajax to the Login Page in site2 ,which authenticates the user name and password against membership database(which site1 need to use too). I want to re-use the existing functionality in site2 as much as possible.

Comment: How exactly would the two sites interact with each other and for what purpose? Your description is a little unclear to me.

Comment: Gumbo,I have added more information to my post. I want to re-use existing authentication logic in site2. I do have access to the code in site2,so does creating a webmethod in site2 login aspx page work?
please let me know if my description is still not clear. I will re-try

Comment: Is the *site2* under your control?

Comment: Yes, I can modify the code for site2